# Iterator value undefined on first run

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In my `onViewCreated()` inside my `MythFragment` I do these steps.

1. Prepopulate Room database.
2. Fetch all records from database into `MutableLiveData<List<..>>`
3. Initialize an iterator to these data
4. Click the "Next" button an check condition `it.hasNext() == true`

For some reason, only during the first run of the program, the `it.hasNext()` gives me `false`. I would expect it to be true, since the steps 1-3 should've already ensured, that the list is filled and the iterator points to the first element.

Interestingly, any later navigation on the `MythView` retrieves the element correctly and `it.hasNext()` gives me `true`.

`MythFragment.kt`

```
class MythFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MythViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.populateMyths()
        viewModel.fetchFromDatabase()

        buttonNextMyth.setOnClickListener {
            mythEvaluation.visibility = View.GONE
            buttonIsThisMythTruthful.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            viewModel.mythsIterator.let {
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    val myth = it.next()
                    mythText.text = myth.myth
                    mythEvaluation.text = myth.evaluation
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "There is no myth, because it.hasNext() is false!)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val action = MythFragmentDirections.actionMenuFragment()
                    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MythViewModel.kt`

```
class MythViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {

    private val myths = MutableLiveData<List<Myth>>()
    lateinit var mythsIterator: Iterator<Myth>

    fun populateMyths() {
        launch {
            val dao = MythDatabase(getApplication()).mythDao()

            if (dao.getRowCount() > 0)
                return@launch

            val mythList = arrayListOf(
                Myth("This is the myth 1", "This is the evaluation of the myth 1"),
                Myth("This is the myth 2", "This is the evaluation of the myth 2"),
                Myth("This is the myth 3", "This is the evaluation of the myth 3"),
                Myth("This is the myth 4", "This is the evaluation of the myth 4"),
                Myth("This is the myth 5", "This is the evaluation of the myth 5")
            )

            dao.insertAll(
                *mythList.toTypedArray()
            )
        }
    }

    fun fetchFromDatabase() {
        launch {
            val mythList = MythDatabase(getApplication()).mythDao().getAllMyths()
            myths.value = mythList
            myths.value?.let {
                mythsIterator = it.iterator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the problem might be in the concurrency (Coroutines), but I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know yet what may be causing this, but is there any particular reason you are using `?.let` instead of `if (mythList != null) { mythsIterator = mythList.iterator(); }`?.  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the line after DB lookup, or logging the number of items in the list?

Comment: BTW you probably don't even need to use `lateinit var`, instead just use a computed property: `val mythsIterator get() = myths.value.iterator()`.  The getter will be called and return a new iterator each time you call it, which is probably better since otherwise you can iterate only once.

Comment: @herman I am just following the practises from a tutorial. Also, I reckoned there is some advatage in `?.let` as it works with "mutating properties" (https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/let-vs-if-not-null/3542). I'm not sure what that is, but it's better to be safe than sorry. I am not really familiar with debugging, I thought it was too difficult. I might give it a try.

Comment: If you check `mythList` for null, that is 100% safe, as it is 1) a val so can't be mutated and 2) local so even if it were a var it couldn't be mutated outside this function.  If null safety was not guaranteed (such as if using a field which can be mutated from outside this function) then Kotlin wouldn't let the code compile (without adding `!!`).  In any case, keeping a single iterator as a property which can only be iterated once doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both functions `populateMyths()` and `fetchFromDatabase()` are launching new coroutines, both these coroutines will run in parallel.  So the first time `fetchFromDatabase()` is called, it may be retrieving the data before `dao.insertAll()` has happened in `populateMyths()`.
Maybe you should rethink / clarify what you aim to accomplish by launching these coroutines.

Comment: I need to prepopulate my database in `populateMyths()` AS SOON AS the application starts. It might thus not be a good idea to place this function into `MythFragment.onViewCreated()`. I MUST make sure the database is prepopulated before `fetchFromDatabase()` is called from `MythFragment`. To achieve this, I tried to move `populateMyths()` to `onCreate()`, but it still is not populated soon enough. Should I call it from MainActivity or MainFragment? Is it a good design decision?

Comment: @Slazer what the best place to init DB is, is kindof another question.  (can't help you there).  But the thing is, it seems you want to run both methods sequentially.  Instead of putting a `launch` block inside each of them, try removing those and add a single `launch` block around the calls to both methods?